# How To Create Sha1- Finger Print in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am  doing Firebase for phone Authentication. I am reading in Forum that Sha1 Finger print is needed for do this. How can i create sha1 finger print. I dont have any keystore file. I am new one to this. so could any one help me.

**Is Sha1 Finger print is needed For Sending Phone Auth Sms in Firebase ?**

Comment: Have you researched already and tried something yourself?

Comment: Are you building for which platform?

Comment: I am building for Android using Unity 2018